# How to use foreach for using regexp

Tags: regex, foreach, tcl

I am using the following code to search for a particular data and store it in a variable.

```
foreach searched $names {
  [regexp {[cell]+} $searched match]
}
```

Here names is the variable which has many data. I am getting an error saying: `Error: invalid command name "1.` I am new to tcl so I cant figure out whats wrong. Is my code correct, will it work? Thanks

Comment: If you're new to Tcl, you would benefit from the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to match a text using regexp and foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436835/trying-to-match-a-text-using-regexp-and-foreach)

Comment: Are you aware that you can edit your question? You don't have to create a brand new question.

Answer (score 4):

Your regexp is evaluating first and `regexp {[cell]+} $searched match` returns `1`, which then becomes:

```
[1]
```

Which is an invalid command. Remove the square brackets:

```
regexp {[cell]+} $searched match
```

Now, I don't think you're using the regexp correctly. This will look for any of the combinations `c`, `e` and `l` at least one time, meaning it'll accept `cell`, `lec` or even `c` alone. You probably want:

```
regexp {((?:cell)+)} $searched match matched
```

This will match `cell`, `cellcell`, `cellcellcell` and so on and store it in the variable `matched`.

Brackets are used to capture matching groups; and these `(?: ...)` are for non capturing groups.

**EDIT:** Following on my comment, I would do something like:

```
set newlist [list]

foreach searched $names {
  regexp {cell\s*\("([^"]+)"\)} $searched match matched
  lappend $newlist $matched
}
```

Now, the list $newlist contains all the matched values. You can do a foreach to display all of them;

```
foreach n $newlist {puts $n}
```

Comment: By the way, `regexp {[cell]+} $searched match` returns either `0` or `1`, `0` meaning no matches and `1` meaning successful match.

Comment: Thanks that helped. My data comes like **cell ("aabbbccc")**, in this the text inside the quotes keeps changing so can you help me how to match these and store it in the variable match? @Jerry

Comment: @user2533429 Thanks, and sorry for the late reply. Timezones mess up a lot of things! Okay, I think what you will be looking for thus would be something like: `regexp {cell\s*\("([^"]+)"\)} $searched match matched` and `matched` will contain `aabbbccc`. I used `[^"]+` to match any character not a quote `"`.

Comment: @user2533429 And since you are looping through a list, I would suggest creating an empty list and append each matched result to that empty list. You can then call it back outside the loop where it will contain all your results. Otherwise, each time you'll overwrite the variable 'matched'.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Its matching now but the only prob is matched is giving me the first value ("aabbcc") only, other values like ("acbbca") are not being matched even if I declare another variable matched1 or so. Should i use a while loop. @Jerry

Comment: @user2533429 Did you try appending the values to a list like I suggested? I edited my answer to provide a sample code for this.

Comment: I tried doing as u mentioned but I am not getting an output at all. Dont have any errors also. My code is : set final_list [list]  foreach searched_data $final {
regexp {cell\s*\("([^"]+)"\)} $searched_data match matched
lappend $final_list $matched  
}  foreach matching_list $final_list { puts $matching_list}  I did this but not getting the output. My file from which I am getting the matched value is text format. DO i have to convert it in list and then use regexp??? @Jerry

Comment: @user2533429 Try using `puts [open "outputfile.txt" w] $matching_list` in the second foreach loop. This will put the matches in a file named `outputfile.txt`. I don't know the contents of your file to give a definite answer. I would use a `while {[gets $file line]} {}` loop and put my regex in, and put the matched in a file immediately after.

Comment: I tried while loop also, my code is like this:   while {[gets $final line]!= -1} {                                                              
puts "LINE IS: $line \n"  regexp {cell\s*\("([^"]+)"\)} $searched_data match matched  
puts "$matched"  
}
But my tool is not working as it is saying the tool has just run out of memory.

Comment: @user2533429 Well, the memory seems to be the problem... what's even the size of the file `$final`?

Comment: This is what it is showing : Out of memory.
(Memory allocated = 1782020 K bytes)
I am not very sure about the size of the file. @Jerry

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment and Jerry answer, I suppose you need

```
regexp -- {(?:cell)\s+?(\("\w+"\))} $searched -> matched_part_in_brakets
puts $matched_part_in_brakets
```

or

```
regexp -- {(?:cell)\s+?(\("\w+"\))} $searched match matched_part_in_brakets
puts $matched_part_in_brakets
```

Comment: I tried this too the answer is same and more repetitive answers are being displayed.