# Trying to match a text using regexp and foreach

Tags: regex, tcl

I am using the following code to match a text like `cell ("acf12bcjd6")`. The values inside the quotes keep changing and I have to capture all of them. The code I used is:

```
foreach searched_data $final {   
    [regexp {cell\(.*\)+} $searched_data match]   
    puts "$match"   
}
```

But I am getting an error saying "can't reach match, no such variable". I do not understand my mistake. Am I doing it correct?

Comment: Can't you just store `.*` using RegEx? `cell \((.*)\)+` then use `\1` to get it.  Also, it seems you missed a space in your expression (or put one in the example)

Comment: FYI: Question was started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17434973/1578604)

Answer (score 1):

Your program is failing because the regexp pattern isn't matching the string, so `match` isn't being set. Try this

```
foreach searched_data $final {
    if {[regexp {cell +\(\"(.*)\"\)} $searched_data junk match]} {
        puts stdout $match
    }
}
```

The pattern assumes that the space between `cell` and the opening bracket is optional. I also assume you want the quotation marks stripped away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead:

```
foreach searched_data $final {   
    set match [regexp {cell ?\([^)]*\)} $searched_data]   
    puts "$match"   
}
```

Comment: What are the square brackets - `[` and `]` - for?

Comment: @nurdglaw negative character class ?

Comment: The error is still the same. The file final is a library file which I opened and read already. Have to match data and store those data which will later be used for sorting. This is my aim.

Comment: I think you'll find that this prints out 1 if the pattern matches and 0 if not.

Comment: It is not printing a 1 or a 0. But when I put the code : puts $match outside the loop I am getting a never ending loop of data from the file but I just want the matched data only. I do no understand this.

Comment: @nurdglaw: In tcl, square brackets act the same as backticks (`) do in bash. In other words, it's a function call

Comment: @slebetman That's not how they were being used when I made the comment.

Comment: You should look at `regexp -inline`…